# Targeting Windows XP SP2 with Visual C++ 2010 (VS2010) SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp-sp2

Is it possible to target Windows XP SP2 with Visual C++ 2010 (VS2010) SP1?
(i.e. do executables built with VC++2010 SP1 run fine on XP SP2?)

Or do MFC/ATL/CRT of VC++2010 SP1 use some APIs not available on XP SP2?

Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks. Do you have any official reference of Microsoft? Did you do some tests with your software? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that you

```
#define  NTDDI_VERSION  0x05010200
```

Before including any Windows header files. This will prevent features that are only supported on Vista and upwards from being made available to you. The value was taken from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745.aspx).

Comment: Or, in alternative, it is possible to use LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress to dynamically load the Windows 7 specific API's only when the app is running on Win7 (and just don't use them on XP).